# Как поймать отклик с сайта в программу на Делфи?

Tags: delphi, php

Назрел такой вопрос: делфи отправляет запрос на сайт, сайт его обрабатывает и должен отправить обратно. Но я не могу понять, как узнать, где это обратно? Делфи приложений будет много... как узнать, что надо отправить именно ему? Как это лучше реализовать с наименьшими трудозатратами?

Comment: Не стесняйтесь, покажите ваш код. Что вы отправляете? как именно вы это делаете?

Comment: Мне кажется это достаточно тривиальная задача, многие с ней сталкивались. Ведь делают же лицензионные программы которые по ключу сверяются с сайтом и наоборот, сайт с программой ?

Comment: ну так и? она заходит по определенному адресу в интернете с какими-то параметрами, получает ответ с какимито параметрами.

Comment: вы определитесь что вы хотите...

Answer (score 1):

Для начала смотреть, как Вы отправляете запрос. Если TWebBrowser, то ждите события OnDocumentComplite, если INDY, то ответ будет в IdHttp. Возьмите снифер и посмотрите, как браузер с сайтом общается.

Comment: Я все равно не понимаю - например я отправил с программы на сайт через пост или гет, сайт обработал данные и ? куда высылать обработанные данные ?

Comment: Var
S:String;
begin
s:=idHttp1.Get('http:\\wwww.blablabla.ru');
end;

Вот в переменной S и будет код который вернул сервер.

Comment: "Вот в переменной S и будет код который вернул сервер." - это я знаю, вопрос был <b>как сервер узнает кому возвращать</b> ? (например таких делфовых программ 1000 штук).

Comment: вы издеваетесь?
а как сервер узнает какому браузеру возвращать, браузеров миллионы.
тот кто отправил запрос тому и вернется.

Comment: вы меня не поняли, возвращать надо не в браузер, а в программму, сооветсвенно и был вопрос, как придать этой программе свой некий идентификатор, что бы передать именно ей ?

Я вам лучше нарисую: Delphi(запрос) -> Site (обработка) -> Delphi (возврат именно тому кто отправлял)

Comment: Это Вы не поняли, сервер вернет ответ **тому кто отправил запрос**, и ему не важно браузер это или программа ваша, индификатора не нужно никакого.
Даже если это будет 1000 ваших программ запущенных одновременно с одного компютера, сервер вернет ответ тому кто отправил запрос.
все условности прописаны на уровне протокола, так что даже не заморачивайтесь.

Comment: @oldzas для начала почитайте про http технологию и не позорьтесь!

зыж даже не так, почитайте КАК работает сеть впринципе. к браузеру или программе и другим приложениям это вообще никакого отношения не имеет.

Comment: @thunder  ничего страшного пусть тренируется, но лучше сразу пусть пробует.

Comment: @savro да тренироваться-то пусть, но это не даст понимания заданных вопросов) тут все гораздо хуже.... :) почему не возникло вопроса про: "я даю деньги продавщице в магазине. КАК она узнает, что сдачу надо отдать мне?", это вот из этого разряда примерно %)

Comment: спасибо за стеб, задело, вопрос все равно не решен.

попробую описать - человек из настолького приложения на делфи отправил через гет или пост данные на сервер, сервер сделал выборку данных, ну и .... куда дальше ? это же был асбтрактный гет запрос .... как найти того кто его послал что бы отправить ему большой объем данных ?

Comment: ну так человек отправил запрос и НЕОТКЛЮЧАЯСЬ ждет ответ от сервера же. если хочется чтобы сервер отдал "когда-то потом", то так не получится. либо в первом запросе получать обратно какойто идентификатор и потом все равно КЛИЕНТ будет подключаться. а я, к примеру, какието ллевые подключения к своему компу не дам. не просто же так поумолчанию все входяжие новые подключения закрыты.

Comment: @oldzas хватит молоть чушь. Прочитайте про протокол HTTP хоть что-то прежде чем задавать такие идиотские вопросы. Если ваш сервер не собирается отправлять данные "сразу", а хочет сначала долго подумать, и потом отправить данные не как ответ на запрос, то это скорее всего не возможно, т. к. у нескольких пользователей может быть один айпи адрес, и "интернет сам ни как не узнает, кому из них предназначается ваш "ответ"

Comment: > это же был асбтрактный гет запрос

С чего ему абстрактным быть-то. Это запрос от конкретного клиента. И все что мы ответим на запрос уйдет именно ему.